# ul li по центру, но точки слева рядом с текстом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Текст выводится из админки, добавление классов, или задать ширину ul и разместить по центру не получится.

Это `text-align: center; list-style-position: inside`

Нужно, чтобы точки были слева в ряд. Это как-то возможно? Или тут без js не обойтись? (вычислять макс ширину самого длинного li, делать ширину ul равной этой макс ширине и размещать по центру)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ul в DOM
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно код?.....

Comment: @meine Весь код ul описан выше, но я приложу скрин сейчас

Comment: дак уберите `text-align: center`, либо перебейте его

Comment: @meine так в том и суть, что мне он нужен,  мне нужно текст в li выровнять по одной линии, но по центру

Comment: text-align: center убираете и к ul делаете flex и с помощью его центрируете уже не каждый  li ,  а всё вместе

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>первый</li>
  <li>второй</li>
  <li>третий</li>
</ul>
```